# Django get user timezone in template

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-timezone

I'm saving date in UTC. I wan't to change that date to automatic user timezone.

my settings

```
USE_TZ = True
```

my template

```
{% for sale in sales %}
    date : {{sale.date}}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried django-tz-detect

https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-tz-detect

but I can't implement that correctly.

Please suggest a good way to solve this issue.

Comment: Are we dealing with User objects here? As in, could we store their timezones in their profile? It would be simpler and likely more accurate than trying to detect it.

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution from [here](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect)

I created a view function

```
@login_required 
@ajax_required
@require_GET
def set_user_timezone(request): 
    timezone = request.GET.get('timezone')
    request.session["set_user_timezone"] = timezone
    response_data = {}
    response_data['status'] = 'true'
    response_data['message'] = 'user timezone set successfully.'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

context

```
if "set_user_timezone" in request.session:
    user_session_ok = True
    user_time_zone = request.session['set_user_timezone']
else:
    user_session_ok = False
    user_time_zone = "Asia/Kolkata"
```

in my base template

```
{% if not user_session_ok %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jstz.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             var timezone = jstz.determine();
             var timezone_name = timezone.name();
             $.ajax({
                url : '/set-user-timezone/',
                action : "GET",
                data : {
                    timezone : timezone_name
                },
                success : function(data){

                },
                error : function(data){

                }
             })
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

my sales template

```
{% for sale in sales %}
    {% load tz %}                       
    date : {{ sale.sale_date|timezone:user_time_zone }}         
{% endfor %}
```

I don't know this is the correct method. but this solution works for me.